# MySQL update table only with the highest values of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

For a game site.
All games are recorded if the player's score is greater than his old score

**Table of all players (over 10,000 players)**

```
CREATE TABLE games (
    PlayerID INT UNSIGNED,
    Date TIMESTAMP(12),
    Score BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
    #...other data
);
```

Once a month, I do an update of the table of records `best`. And after I erase all `games`.

**Table of best players (top 50)**

```
CREATE TABLE best (
    #...same as games, without final other data
    PlayerID INT UNSIGNED,
    Date TIMESTAMP(12),
    Score BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0
);
```

So I add the 50 best players of the table `games` in to the table `best`:

```
INSERT INTO best (PlayerID, Date, Score)
   SELECT PlayerID, Date, Score FROM games ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT 50;
```

And after (and this is where I have a problem) I try to keep in `best` only the best 50. At this point `best` contains 100 lines.

**What I have to do:**

- Do not store several times the same player `PlayerID`.
- Delete the worst `Score` for this player.
- And at the end, leaving only the top 50.

->

```
+----------+---------+
| PlayerID | Score   |
+----------+---------+
| 25       | 20000   | New
| 25       | 25000   | Old best
| 40       | 10000   | Old best
| 57       | 80000   | New best
| 57       | 45000   | Old
| 80       | 35000   | New best
+----------+---------+
```

I have to retain in the end only 50 lines (the ones with "best" in my example).
I tried many things, but I have not succeeded in achieve the expected result.

I am using PHP, so if it is possible to do it simply with a intermediare storage in an array, that's fine too.
The speed is not a priority because it is an operation that is done only once a month.

Comment: Couldn't you query on the players' table to find best ones instead of creating a new table?

Comment: @Phate01 Yes I do that for a month. But at the end of the month I clear the game table. Everything is reset to zero.  I just keep track of the top 50 of all time ...

Comment: Ok so you can merge your selection with the best table using [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: @Phate01 And in the end replace the entire contents with the result? And erase the last lines to keep only 50. I do not know which way to turn the request with the tests better Scores and PlayerID equality.

Comment: Umm.. why not truncate **best** before running the insert?

Comment: @ethrbunny There are already 50 lines only before the insert.

Comment: Sure - but since there is no guarantee that a given player will reappear you can't limit the duplication with an index. The table needs to be recreated every time so why not take the easy route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SQL returns the top 50 scores:

```
SELECT `PlayerId`, max(`Score`) MaxScore
FROM (
    SELECT `PlayerId`, `Date`, `Score` FROM games    
    UNION
    SELECT `PlayerId`, `Date`, `Score` FROM best    
) t
GROUP BY `PlayerId`
ORDER BY `MaxScore` DESC
LIMIT 50
```

You can use the result to overwrite the table `best`. For this you also need the corresponding `Date` field, which is missing so far. The next SQL will also return a `maxDate` field which corresponds to the highscore.

```
SELECT t2.`PlayerId`, max(t2.`Date`) maxDate, top.`MaxScore`  
FROM
    (   
        SELECT `PlayerId`, max(`Score`) MaxScore
        FROM (
            SELECT `PlayerId`, `Date`, `Score` FROM games    
            UNION
            SELECT `PlayerId`, `Date`, `Score` FROM best    
        ) t1
        GROUP BY `PlayerId`
        ORDER BY `MaxScore` DESC
        LIMIT 50
    ) top
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT `PlayerId`, `Date`, `Score` FROM games    
        UNION
        SELECT `PlayerId`, `Date`, `Score` FROM best    
    ) t2 ON t2.`PlayerId` = top.`PlayerId` AND t2.`Score` = top.`MaxScore`
GROUP BY t2.`PlayerId`
ORDER BY top.`MaxScore` DESC
```

To transfer the new top 50 highscores into the `best` table you can use a temporary table like `tmp_best`. Insert the top scores into the empty table `tmp_best` with (you have to insert your select query from above):

```
INSERT INTO tmp_best (`PlayerId`, `Date`, `Score`) 
    SELECT ...
```

After this the `best` table can be emptied and then you can copy the rows from `tmp_best` into `best`.

---

Here is an **alternative solution**, which has simplified SQL. The difference 
to the solution above is the using of a temporary table `tmp_all` at the beginning for the unified data. Before using the following SQL you have to create `tmp_all`, which can be a copy of the structure of `games` or `best`.

```
DELETE FROM tmp_all;

INSERT INTO tmp_all
    SELECT `PlayerId`, `Date`, `Score` FROM games    
    UNION
    SELECT `PlayerId`, `Date`, `Score` FROM best    
;

DELETE FROM best;

INSERT INTO best (`PlayerId`, `Date`, `Score`) 
    SELECT t2.`PlayerId`, max(t2.`Date`) maxDate, top.`MaxScore`  
    FROM
        (   
            SELECT `PlayerId`, max(`Score`) MaxScore
            FROM tmp_all t1
            GROUP BY `PlayerId`
            ORDER BY `MaxScore` DESC
            LIMIT 50
        ) top
        LEFT JOIN tmp_all t2 ON t2.`PlayerId` = top.`PlayerId` AND t2.`Score` = top.`MaxScore`
    GROUP BY t2.`PlayerId`
    ORDER BY top.`MaxScore` DESC
;
```

Comment: Thank you. I do not have the ability to immediately test. May I ask how I can overwrite the table `best` in the same query.

Comment: @Croises I would use a temporary table. After creating a temporary table with the new values you can empty the `best` table and copy the rows from the temporary table.

Comment: I have to test. But I think I can use a simpler solution, such as @Phate01because I have only one entry per player. I only records the highest score per player during the month. And in this case, I do not have to use `max()`.But I must get the same result simply with sorts (?)

Comment: @Croises As soon as you union the selects you can have two entries for one user, from the table `best` and the table `games`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was thinking just now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PlayerID, Date, Score FROM games ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT 50
UNION
SELECT PlayerID, Date, Score FROM best
```

Here you'll get the best 50 players all-time. Then, as suggested by @ethrbunny, erase the best table and populate it again with the above query. You can use a [TEMPORARY TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

UNION guarantees you that you'll get no duplicated player

Comment: Thank you. I can't erase the `best` table before if you use it in your query ?

Comment: Since I haven't tested it, try first the selection to see if it works. Then you can simply drop it with `DROP TABLE` and then recreate it with `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: @Croises If you empty your table before using it to select your data, there will be no data any more!

Comment: "UNION guarantees you that you'll get no duplicated player" - this is not true.

Comment: Yes that was that my doubt. I wondered on what data the test was done. Because only the PlayerID can be the same. And in this case, there is never two identical lines.